# Deflater entropy issue

Tags: java, base64, compression, deflate

I'm using `Deflater` to send some messages over the net.

I'm using:

```
public static byte[] compress(byte[] data,int level) throws IOException {

     Instant starts = Instant.now();

     Deflater deflater = new Deflater();  
     deflater.setInput(data);  
     deflater.setLevel(/*level*/9);

     ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(data.length);   
     deflater.finish();  

     byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];   
     while (!deflater.finished()) {  
          int count = deflater.deflate(buffer); // returns the generated code... index  
          outputStream.write(buffer, 0, count);   
     }  
     outputStream.close();  
     byte[] output = outputStream.toByteArray();  
     System.out.println("Original: " + data.length / 1024 + " Kb");  
     System.out.println("Compressed: " + output.length / 1024 + " Kb");  

     Instant ends = Instant.now();
     System.out.println("deflating time:"+Duration.between(starts, ends));

     return output;  
}
```

to compress a generic byte array,

and:

```
msg.setDataString(Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(data));
```

to embed the object in an xml.

All did work fine for a while, but today using the debugger i saw:

```
msg.dataString
```

(this is a set of almost void images as rgb pixel(3byte) arrays)

```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```

With a really scary lack of entropy, obviously I'm doing something really wrong to get this result, and I'm wasting bandwidth, *or* that sequence of "A"'s is valid information. But that's just scary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happened there is that the compression ability of the deflate format was saturated for the first part of the data. The maximum compression ratio possible in deflate is 1032:1.

In the data that was compressed, the first 1,083,300 bytes are all zero. Almost all of that compressed down to about 1,000 zero bytes.

All is well. You are doing nothing wrong. No worries.

Comment: thanks,so basicly its over 9 thousand XD ... im sending up to 5 packets x second and a 45k/s optimization seems a must... ill look into that. Any method that you can tell to spot and cut the useless sequence? maybe should i choose another compression strategy allthogeter?

Comment: If you expect to send a lot of these empty images, then you could simply compress it a second time. That 2,416 bytes compresses down to 1,403 bytes on the second compression.

Comment: wouldnt it be compressed by a 1032 factor to few bytes? would you advise a level 9 deflating and a second level 1 deflating?

Comment: The series of 1000 zeros _is_ in fact compressed down to a few bytes. However there is another 1400 bytes of compressed data that is not compressed at all the second time.

Comment: The second compression can be level 1, and it should pick up the simple run length encoding. Just experiment with the levels and see what works best for you.

Comment: thanks, i was googling to some further improvement to my understandings and your name did pop out as an authority.. so could i ask you one further question? if i have a series of frames and i put them togheter and compress them as a chunk i would expect some extra redoundancy but in some cases the compression actually decreases in %, i tought maybe im using something like the equivalent of a larger color table and so each pixel needs more bits? is there some n-dimensional compression format (if i visualize the frame number as third axis i would expect some exploitable locality in compression)?

Comment: Maybe, simply add a Run Length Encoding as a first step before deflating.